# How to prove the period of a trigonometric function decreases?

Tags: real-analysis

Let's imagine I have a function $f(x)=\sin x$. We know that the period is going to be $2\pi$. Same idea when we think of $\cos x$. What I am saying is, that the period as $x \to \infty$ remains the same, that is, in the case of our $f(x)$, we are going to have $f(x)=0$ when $x=2\pi k$ $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let's now suppose I have a function $h(x)=\sin(e^x)$. In this case the period, or in other words, the wavelength (which I know are two different things, I mean only that they both undergo these changes) decreases towards $0$ as $x \to \infty$.

My question for you now is:

How can we put this concept in mathematical terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you want to know when your funcion $h(x)=y_0$. Then you would have a succesion $x_n$ such that:

$$h(x_n)=y_0 \iff \sin{\exp{x_n}}=y_0 \iff \exp{x_n}=\arcsin{y_0}+2n\pi \iff x_n=\ln{2n\pi+\arcsin{y_0}}$$

Therefore the "distance" between two succesive events, the "period" would be:

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\ln{\frac{\arcsin{y_0}+(n+1)2\pi}{\arcsin{y_0}+n2\pi}}$$

Which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Splendid! Thank you a lot, kind sir!

Comment: @E.S.L. no problem! I hope it helped